# Convergence of measures on any interval

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider Borel probability measures $\{\mu_n\},\mu$ on $\mathbf R$ such that
$$\mu_n([a,b])=\int\limits_{\mathbf R}\mathbf 1_{[a,b]} \ d\mu_n \longrightarrow \int\limits_{\mathbf R} \mathbf 1_{[a,b]}\ d\mu = \mu([a,b])$$

for any interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbf R.$ Is there a name for this particular type of convergence of measures? As far as I know this is not a weak convergence.

Comment: [Setwise convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) is a very hot candidate. Work that is left to do: figure out if the convergence holds for all Borel sets when it holds for closed intervals.

Comment: Sometimes this is called setwise convergence of measures.